# Как отредактировать вставку текста в input?

Tags: javascript, html

Есть маска на input - +7 (***)***-**-**. Я пытаюсь добиться, чтобы в это поле при вставке 88269269922, +78269269922 и 9269269922 оставалось только 9269269922 (то есть 8/+7 стиралась, так как уже есть +7 в маске).

```
const maskOptions = {
    mask: '+7(000)000-00-00',
    lazy: false
}
var phoneMask = new IMask(phoneInput, maskOptions);
```

Хотелось бы, чтобы и при вводе 50-значного текста, в маске (в input) отображались только 10 последних цифр. Например:

- +7 (***)***-**-**
  +7 (9__)***-**-__
  +7 (92*)***-**-__
  +7 (926)***-**-__
  +7 (926)8__-**-**
  +7 (926)89_-**-**
  +7 (926)898-4_-__
  +7 (926)898-45-__
  +7 (926)898-45-2_
  +7 (926)898-45-28 (дальше я кликаю новую цифру **3** и она добавится в конец, сместив все остальное)
  +7 (268)984-52-8**3**

Comment: Если вставлять в инпут заготовленный номер, то +7 и 8 само стирается. Я попробовал так сделать в официальной документации https://imask.js.org/. Зачем Вам сдвиг, когда вводится лишняя цифра?

Comment: Неа, я зашла на прикрепленную Вами ссылку. Вставила 89266547722, получилось +78926654772. То есть 8 осталась, последняя цифра стерлась.

Comment: Значит это минус данной библиотеки)